# Gradle scan without transmitting info?

Tags: gradle

According to [Gradle's official website](https://scans.gradle.com/#:%7E:text=Publishing%20a%20Build%20Scan%20to%20scans.gradle.com%20transmits%20information%20about%20your%20Gradle%20and%20Maven%20builds%20and%20their%20environment%20to%20Gradle%27s%20servers.):

> Publishing a Build Scan to scans.gradle.com transmits information about your Gradle and Maven builds and their environment to Gradle's servers.

Is there a way to run a build scan so I can view the output locally, without transmitting the information to Gradle's server? Maybe something like

`gradle build --scan-without-transmit`

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no way to run a build scan and evaluate the results locally without sending information to Gradle's infrastructure. This feature is reserved to [Gradle Enterprise](https://gradle.com/).

Please note that the build scan URL is randomly generated and can be deleted anytime.

> The information is only accessible via a randomly generated link, printed at the end of the build. You can delete the Build Scan when you are finished.
>
> A Build Scan that has not been viewed within 3 months of being created will be removed. Once a Build Scan has been viewed, it will be available indefinitely.

Comment: "random url that can be deleted" is good enough for many private users, but no company that I've ever worked for would allow the use of such a tool to potentially leak internal build details. I understand that Gradle needs to earn money, but it's a real bummer that this functionality is only available in the much bigger Gradle Enterprise package.

Comment: Especially now Gradle insists you to use build scans to find potential issues for upgrades from 7.x to 8.x. Not good enough.

Comment: This is really somewhat awful. Basically either make it a paid plugin - which would be fine, after all companies need to somehow earn money, too, or make it available to people and companies even if that includes having to self-host a server component, run some application or something. Otherwise it makes you - as a company - look weird and **it feels like** if you could charge people for Gradle itself and have your users leak data to you, you definitely would do that.

Answer (score 8):

It's possible to use the `--profile` flag locally instead of `--scan`.

From [the docs](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_performance:%7E:text=is%20normal.-,%2D%2Dprofile,in%20the%20%24buildDir/reports/profile%20directory.%20%2D%2Dscan%20is%20preferred.,-%2D%2Dscan):

> `--profile`
>
> Generates a high-level performance report in the `$buildDir/reports/profile` directory. `--scan` is preferred.